# Look for a value inside a set

Tags: c++, boost, boost-hana

I have the following code:

```
auto mySet = hana::make_set(2, "hi", 3.0);
```

How do I get the value a particular type?:

```
std::cout << mySet[???] << std::endl;
```

Like 'mySet[char*]' or something. Does set work for this, or must I use a map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a map. If you think of it in different terms, what you really seem to want is a `std::unordered_map<Type, Object>` (i.e. the keys are types and the values are, well, values). Instead, what you did is use `std::unordered_set<Object>`, where the keys are the same as the values.

So instead, you should write

```
auto myMap = hana::make_map(
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<int>, 2),
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<char const*>, "hi"),
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<double>, 3.0)
);
std::cout << myMap[hana::type_c<char const*>] << std::endl;
```

Otherwise, you can also use a set and then find your element in it using `hana::find_if` with a predicate that would check the type of the object. But this is going to be less compile-time efficient, because `hana::find_if` must do a linear search.

Comment: As a side note, a corollary of the above reasoning is that `hana::set` is only ever useful to hold objects that can be compared at compile-time, since these objects will be used as keys. So basically, `hana::set` is almost useless for anything runtime, while `hana::map` can still hold meaningful runtime values, as long as the keys are compile-time.

Comment: I could see `hana::set` being used with run-time values if all of the types were unique and `hana::Comparable`. In some cases, making it could be more efficient than a map because it wouldn't be making pairs, and the symbol length could probably be a lot shorter.

Comment: What would `hana::find` return? It has to return a `hana::optional`, whose optional-ness has to be known at compile time. Hence, the keys have to be comparable __at compile-time__. Note that the same applies to `hana::tuple`, but at least `hana::tuple` can be accessed using indices too, so it makes sense to have runtime values in a tuple.